# Umount + can't umount

Tags: linux

I can't umount on my Linux machine and not by umount -f
please advice?

```
[root@Linux umount /mnt/cdrom
  umount: /mnt/cdrom: device is busy
  umount: /mnt/cdrom: device is busy
```

Comment: This question should probably have been asked on http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com since it is about using a linux system, not administering it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use fuser to see which processes are still using that mount:

```
fuser -mu /mnt/cdrom
```

If you want to kill those processes via fuser, use `-k`:

```
fuser -mk /mnt/cdrom
```

I often (as in: I wish I had a nickel every time...) find myself unable to umount because I've cd'd to a mount as myself then su'd to root.  My old shell is still on the mount point so I can't umount.  Try exiting the root shell and see if your user's shell is still cd'd to something under `/mnt/cdrom`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to figure out what is using the tile system in the mount and stop those process. You can get an idea of what might be there by running `lsof | grep /mnt/cdrom` to see what procses have that folder open. You might start by closing any file managers and cd'ing out of there from any terminals.

Comment: I dont have lsof command -:(

Comment: Then install it or use `fuser` instead if you have that.

Comment: Dude thank you. No fuser options would show the loop device being used but lsof worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably viewing the CD from a console or file browser without realising. Linux won't let you unmount it if it's in use.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about what may be using the device you can `umount -f /mnt/cdrom` which will force it to be unmounted.